# COALESCE in Where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Is there a good way to express within SQL to select a specific row if a column is matched, otherwise to select a more general row? Something like:

```
SELECT name FROM names 
            WHERE (colA = @colA OR colA = 'ALL')
```

I just want it to return the one specific record if it exists, otherwise return the generic "ALL" record if it can't find a specific column match. It seems like COALESCE would be similar to what I'm looking for, but I don't know how that could work here syntactically.

Comment: That's going to always return the `ALL` row, as well as the one you specify. Is that what you want?

Comment: I guess you could use `where ColA in (@colA, 'ALL')`, which is a bit shorter.

Comment: Actually that's my question. I know the SELECT statement I have here is not going to work for my intended purpose. It seems like there should be a way to do this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Blorgbeard answer (using top 1 and order by) is probably the best way but just to be different you could also use a sub-query and not exists:

```
SELECT name FROM names 
WHERE (colA = @colA) OR (colA = 'ALL' AND NOT EXISTS(
                                                SELECT name FROM names 
                                                WHERE colA = @colA))
```

I guess the "advantage" of this is that it uses more standard sql.

Comment: That will return exactly the same result-set as the original query - if colA='ALL', and @colA<>'ALL', then the `colA != @colA` bit is redundant, yes?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - yes you are right I removed that code.

Answer (score 2):

This query, although not pretty, should do what you want:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name FROM names 
WHERE (colA = @colA OR colA = 'ALL') 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN colA='ALL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Edit: For multiple columns, I think what you would want is this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name FROM names 
WHERE (colA = @colA AND colB = @colB) OR (colA = 'ALL') 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN colA='ALL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

I'm assuming that there is just one `ALL` row, so there's no need to check for `colB='ALL'`, and that the "key" for the table is `colA` and `colB` combined - so you're not interested in rows where `colA` matches but `colB` doesn't, for example.

Comment: thanks, this looks the best to me so far. Would this still work for multiple columns? IE: SELECT TOP 1 name, otherName FROM names WHERE (colA=@colA OR colA='ALL') AND (colB=@colB OR colB='ALL') ORDER BY CASE WHEN colA='ALL' THEN 1 ELSE 0, CASE WHEN colB='ALL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Comment: IE? I think you lost a bit of comment there. But yes, it could be adapted to multiple "key" columns, and of course multiple output columns can just be added to the `select` list.

Comment: Ah, you edited it :) Are `colA` and `colB` a combined key? So, you want the row that has `colA=@colA AND colB=@colB`, or if no such row exists, then you want the `ALL` row?

Comment: Actually this isn't a composite key look up. I just wanted to be able to have my default values for when there is no specific match on these particular columns. So maybe the multiple column lookup isn't going to work this way.

Comment: OK, you might be right. It might be a good idea to ask a new question  for the multiple columns variation, and give an example of some data, and the results you want out of that data.

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE is useful when joining multiple tables and you want the first non-null value in specific order.

Ex.

```
SELECT
   TheID=COALESCE(Table1.TheID,Table2.TheID,NULL)
FROM
   Table1 
   INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.TheID=Table2.TheID
```

One alternative way to achieve what you are asking apart from the example you posted would be to set a nullable parameter and only match if it has a value:

Ex.

```
CREATE Test(@Param1 INT=NULL)
AS
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    (@Param1 IS NULL OR IDField=@Param1)
```

If all non-matching records require a record as well as matches then I guess you could join the table on itself to get matches and mismatched.

```
SELECT
    Calc=CASE WHEN Table2.IDField IS NULL THEN Table.Value ELSE 'ALL' END
FROM
    Table
    INNER JOIN Table Table2 ON Table2.IDField<>@Param1
WHERE
    (Table.IDField=@Param1)
```

Comment: thanks, the nullable paramater I would like to avoid. I want to send in a specific value for the parameter, and match on that parameter if it is there. If it is not, I want to match on the row with "ALL" as the columns value.

Comment: The last example, although a bit awkward, will return what you need.