# Selecting default values when specific values don't exist in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am having difficulty finding a good way to selecting a column by a default value, when a specific value doesn't exist.

```
SELECT TOP 1 colD, colE FROM table where (colA = @colA OR colA = 'default') 
      AND (colB = @colB OR colB = 'default') 
      AND (colC = @colC OR colC = 'default')
```

The problem with the above query of course is that it might return the row with the 'default' value when the specific value actually exists in the table. Is there an approved (hopefully clean) way to do something like this? I would think I need to have ORDER BY in there, but I'm not really sure how to best handle this for multiple columns.

I would like to not have to pass a null value in for the parameter. I want to pass a specific value in and check if that specific value exists in the column, if not return the 'default' value.

Comment: In your own words, what do you mean by "default value"?

Comment: Do you mean to return only the columns you are searching by?

Comment: I want to add default rows that the query will fall through to if it doesn't find an exact match.

Comment: Does `table` have other columns besides just `colA, colB, colC`?

Comment: the table does have other columns besides colA, colB, and colC. Also, the columns in the search are not being returned in the select.

Comment: Ok, one more question:  is there already a single row in `table` that is populated with the default values for `ColA, ColB, ColC`?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I think this is what you need.  Included some questions and explained my assumptions within the tsql comments.

```
--Can NULL be passed in for any of the parameters?
--Adjust this logic (or remove it) to suit your needs.
IF @colA IS NULL OR @colB IS NULL OR @colC IS NULL
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('<Your stored proc name>:  all input params must be non-NULL.', 16, 1);
    RETURN;
END

--Search for the row with the input search params.
--(You're searching for an "exact match", right?)
SELECT TOP (1) ColD, ColE
FROM table 
WHERE colA = @colA 
AND colB = @colB 
AND colC = @colC 

--If not found, search for the row with the default ColA/B/C values.
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    SELECT TOP (1) ColD, ColE
    FROM table 
    WHERE colA = 'Default ColA value' 
    AND colB = 'Default ColB value'  
    AND colC = 'Default ColC value'  

--If still not found, raise an error.
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RAISERROR('<Your stored proc name>:  no matching row found and no default row found.', 16, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyone's feedback, I ended up using this kind of query, but for multiple columns and it looks like it's getting the job done. Thanks to user Hogan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623332/coalesce-in-where-clause/22623437?noredirect=1#comment34452132_22623437)

```
SELECT name FROM names 
WHERE (colA = @colA) OR (colA = 'ALL' AND NOT EXISTS(
                                                SELECT name FROM names 
                                                WHERE colA = @colA))
```